# How to choose a pressure cooker specifically for legumes/beans and which setting is appropriate?

Tags: beans, pressure-cooker, legumes

I am interested in buying a pressure cooker. I have only 2 requirements:

1. The **only** food I want to use it for is legumes/beans (mentioning it case it matters in any way).
2. Take little space

I have been checking some electric ones, but from their programs mentioned I don't see anything mentioned about legumes. Models I checked are e.g. `Turbo Cuisine CY7548 Multicooker` and `Tefal All-in-One CY505E - 3 in 1 Slow Cooker - Multicooker - Pressure Cooker - Stainless Steel`, just for example. Neither has a “beans / legumes” program.

So which setting am I supposed to choose (e.g. `soup`) when cooking beans if I bought a pressure cooker without a “beans” setting?

Is there anything else I should consider when choosing a pressure cooker?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its a shopping request - any answers will be opinion based and links to products become outdated quickly, so not suitable for SE sites.

Comment: @bob1: I am not asking for a specific product but what is the usual program for legumes

Answer (score 4):

Many Instant Pot models have a ‘beans’ button, but usually the manual setting is all that you really need.

What’s more important is the type of mechanism that it uses for maintaining pressure.  Most electric pressure cookers have a ‘locking’ vs a ‘jiggler’ mechanism.  The jigglers will release steam the whole time that you’re cooking which means you’re losing liquid.  (There are other styles… the important part is if it’s letting steam escape as it cooks)

Some of the electric pressure cookers also have sensors that are useful when cooking things that may thicken the liquid … if they notice that the temperature at the bottom of the pot gets too hot, it will shut off the heat to allow it to soften and disperse, then will continue.  If it happens again, it will alarm that something it wrong (the older Instant Pots will show ‘burn’ on the LCD display)

I don’t know which specific brands or models have those features, but I would recommend the locking type with burn detection if you’re cooking beans.

The issue is going to be the ‘takes little space’ as electric pressure cookers tend to be much bulkier than stove-top ones.  There are a range of sizes in capacities which affects their overall size, so you may need to look around to find one that will deal with the volume that you’re hoping to cook, and no larger.

(And note that as most electric pressure cookers are ‘multi cookers’, their total capacity is NOT the same as their pressure cooker capacity.  Instant Pot says to only fill it 2/3 when pressure cooking, so a 6qt model should only be filled to 4 quarts)

Comment: When you say locking type you mean an electric one? While jigglers are the traditional kitchen stove/gas top ones?

Comment: Not necessarily. It’s more about regional preferences - in Europe, locking is standard even for stovetop models.

Comment: If we use the 2 examples I give in the post from Tefal, which characteristics cover the specs you are talking about so I understand what to look out for?

Comment: @Stephie: ^ same question

Comment: @Jim : there are styles that either use weights or springs to regulate the pressure.  You have to adjust the heat so there is just a little bit of steam escaping (if there isn’t, then it’s below pressure).  The weighted ones are the ‘jiggler’ ones because the weight bounces around while letting steam out.  The locking ones have two pressure gauges… one that locks when the pressure is achieved, and a second that releases if it is too far over pressure.  Most electric ones use this sort

Comment: And I should mention that sometimes the over-pressure valve is the silicone gasket.  It’s designed to collapse or otherwise fail when it’s over-pressure, so always make sure that if you replace it that you buy the right one

Comment: @Joe: When you say to search for the ones that are of the type `locking type with burn detection` how is this usually phrased in specs?

Comment: @Joe: e.g. here https://www.tefal.co.uk/Cooking-appliances/Pressure-Cookers/Pressure-Cookers/Turbo-Cuisine-CY754840-Multi-Pressure-Cooker-%E2%80%93-4-8L-Black/p/7211004513 is there anything mentioned about burn detection? I am not sure how I would find this phrased across various brands

Comment: @Joe: Here I can't find something similar phrased either. Does it mean these brands don't support the burn detection? Or it can be phrased differently depending the brand?

Comment: Also can't find something about burn detection for `instant pot pro crisp 11-in-1`

Comment: If you read the Instant Pot manual, section troubleshooting, you’ll find the burn detection. In all manuals you’ll see diagrams of the valves and can see that they are locking.